# How to remove smell from new wooden cupboard?

Tags: smell

There is a distinct "woody" sort of smell from newly purchased wooden cupboards. Is there a way to remove it such that when I open the cupboards, I will not smell this distinct sort of "woody" smell?

Comment: If you don't like the smell of wood, you're on the wrong site ;)

Comment: What's wrong with the smell of wood?

Comment: @Tester101, I don't mean that I don't like the smell of wood but the wooden cupboard "woody" smell very weird as it don't smell like a "pure" wood even though it is a wooden cupboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like new car smell and will go away on its own over time. While you can mask the smell with air freshners, there is nothing I am aware of that will instantly remove the smell. Keeping the doors open for a while will help speed up this process.

Baking soda (like how you'd use it in a fridge) might help a bit too.

Comment: Newspaper and brownpaper bags are also helpful with odors. Lining the shelves will help, too.